# Spotify 404 Error when trying to add songs to queue using Spotify API

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I have an array of Spotify URIs in the format:

```
spotify:track:3OF9rTCYjLEplmYMynYvHG
```

I am trying to use the API to add each value in the array to the queue. My code is as follows:

```
        for (const uri of array.slice(0, max)) {
        let result = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/queue? 
uri=${uri}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        });

        console.log(result);

        if (result.status === 404) {
            console.log(`Track not found in Spotify catalog: ${uri}`);
        } else if (result.ok) {
            console.log(`Successfully added ${uri} to queue`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Error adding ${uri} to queue. Status: ${result.status}`);
        }

    }
```

I keep getting caught with the error:

```
Track not found in Spotify catalog: spotify:track:3OF9rTCYjLEplmYMynYvHG
```

And the response looks like this:

```
Response {
size: 0,
timeout: 0,
[Symbol(Body internals)]: {
 body: Gunzip {
  _writeState: [Uint32Array],
  _readableState: [ReadableState],
  _events: [Object: null prototype],
  _eventsCount: 5,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState: [WritableState],
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  bytesWritten: 0,
  _handle: [Zlib],
  _outBuffer: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 97 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 00 00 00 97 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 00 ... 16334 more bytes>,
  _outOffset: 0,
  _chunkSize: 16384,
  _defaultFlushFlag: 2,
  _finishFlushFlag: 2,
  _defaultFullFlushFlag: 3,
  _info: undefined,
  _maxOutputLength: 4294967296,
  _level: -1,
  _strategy: 0,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kCallback)]: null,
  [Symbol(kError)]: null
},
disturbed: false,
error: null
  },
 [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
  url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/queue? 
uri=spotify:track:3OF9rTCYjLEplmYMynYvHG',
status: 404,
statusText: 'Not Found',
headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
counter: 0
  }
}
```

1. I performed an Audio Analysis and the songs are being read fine. It's literally just when I try to add them to the queue I get an error.
2. When I print the access token, it prints fine so that isn't the issue. My API requests are also working for all other areas of the web app.
3. Also, this was working before but then I split up different parts of the code into separate .html pages so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it? Doesn't make sense to me though because it's accessing the songs fine.
4. I also tried to use just the Spotify ID, and not the URI, and that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Turns out Spotify has a bug (?) where you can only add songs to the playback queue if a song is already playing. I did not specify a device so it only registers as active if a song is playing I guess? I'll try specifying a device but just wanted to post an update just in case someone else has this issue.

Comment: I would recommend to check if there's an open issue on that in Github, and link the thread here.
In the future, people who get similar errors will come to this post, not knowing if it's still relevant and if their problem can be resolved.